# how to bring result of column in next line based on length of result in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, split, oracle10g

Suppose that I have a column which is getting following string inserted after execution of query:

```
"WE welcome you all to the ceremony"
```

Now i want first 15 characters in first line of column and remaining characters in next line as below:

```
WE welcome you
all to the ceremony
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

SUBSTR is capable of doing that:

```
SQL> with test as (select 'WE welcome you all to the ceremony' col from dual)
  2  select substr(col, 1, 15) ||
  3         chr(10) ||
  4         substr(col, 16) result
  5  from test;

RESULT
-----------------------------------
WE welcome you
all to the ceremony
```

However, with a different input string things might change and look stupid:

```
SQL> with test as (select 'WE welcome Harry Potter to the ceremony' col from dual)
  2  select substr(col, 1, 15) ||
  3         chr(10) ||
  4         substr(col, 16) result
  5  from test;

RESULT
----------------------------------------
WE welcome Harr
y Potter to the ceremony
```

What would you like to do in such a case? One option is to split a string on the first space before 15th character; for example:

```
SQL> with test as (select 'WE welcome Harry Potter to the ceremony' col from dual)
  2  select
  3    substr(col, 1, instr(col, ' ', 1, regexp_count(substr(col, 1, 15), ' '))) ||
  4    chr(10) ||
  5    substr(col, instr(col, ' ', 1, regexp_count(substr(col, 1, 15), ' ')) + 1) result
  6  from test;

RESULT
----------------------------------------
WE welcome
Harry Potter to the ceremony
```

Other options are possible, but you should explain what to do in which situation.